# How to restrict the number of iterations of a nested for loop to only cases where the loop counters are different?

Tags: python, for-loop, nested-loops

I am trying to write a simple program that can identify lists within a 'list of lists' that have the same 'zeroth' element.

My attempt is below.

Since my construction considers cases where the e.g. i= 0, j=1 and i=1,j=0 to be different, I end up printing out twice as many lists as I need.

I know that I can use list(set(indices_of_repeats)) to remove the duplicates but this doesn't really directly address the underlying issue, which is that I want to understand how to place a condition on the values that my loop counters (is that the correct terminology?) take relative to each other, and not bother to iterate over cases where that condition is not met.

Also, I invite any suggestions for faster/more elegant/more pythonic ways to write this program.

```
list = [[1,2], [2,3], [4,5], [4,6],[4,7]]

indices_of_repeats = []
for i in range(0,len(list)):
    for j in range(0,len(list)):
        if list[i][0] == list[j][0] and i !=j:
            indices_of_repeats.append(list[i])
print (indices_of_repeats)
```

EDIT:

I've come up with the following - this works but any better suggestions are welcome.

```py
list = [[4,5],[1,2], [2,3], [4,6],[4,7]]
repeats = []
  for i in range(len(list)):
      for j in range(len(list)):
          if list[i][0] == list[j][0] and i!=j:
              repeats.append(list[i])
              break
print (repeats)
```

Comment: I'd probably use a dictionary/hashmap object.

Comment: ```
map = {}
for list_item in lists:
  if(map[list[0]]):
    map[list[0]].add(list)
  else:
    map[list[0] = [list]

indicies_or_repeats = filter(lambda x: len(map[x]) > 1, map.keys())
```

Answer (score 0):

This one is simple, since you want only one instance of each combination.  Simply start your inner loop counter *above* the outer one:

```
for i in range(0, len(list)):
    for j in range(i+1, len(list)):
        if list[i][0] == list[j][0]:
            indices_of_repeats.append(list[i])
```

Output:

```
[(2, 3), (2, 4), (3, 4)]
```

These are the indices of pairs with matching first elements.
    [[4, 5], [4, 5], [4, 6]]

This isn't particularly descriptive: you print the first element of the matching pair in each case.  I suspect you need something better, such as pairs of indices:

```
            indices_of_repeats.append( (i, j) )
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
I realise I've been a bit unclear in how i've named my variables. I really just want to return the lists with common first elements i.e. [[4,5], [4,6], [4,7]].

Following your advice, my output reads [[4, 5], [4, 5], [4, 6]]. Whereas I want [[4, 5], [4, 6], [4, 7]]. What do you suggest?

Comment: If you want all of the common elements, then you need to add them to the list.  You've added only the first element of each matching pair, which *guarantees* that you'll miss the last element in each such group.  Instead, add *both* elements, provided they're not already in the list.  Alternately, add them both as pairs (2-tuples) and use a set to remove duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple solution with just an extra condition in the `if`. It's not efficient, but it does not seem like you have thousands of items to process.

```
list = [[1,2], [2,3], [4,5], [4,6],[4,7]]

indices_of_repeats = []
for i in range(0,len(list)):
    for j in range(0,len(list)):
        if list[i][0] == list[j][0] and i !=j and list[i] not in indices_of_repeats:
            indices_of_repeats.append(list[i])
print (indices_of_repeats)
```